# WPF MVVM handle window closing at 'X'

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I read about this in many posts, but still don't understand how to handle window closing at 'X'. E.g. i need to ask a question before closing.

I try to use "interaction":

```
<Window x:Class="Sem5_CP.Views.AirlineManagerView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:test.Views"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="AirlineManagerView" Height="300" Width="300">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Closing">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ExitCommand}"  />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <Grid Style="{StaticResource MainGridStyle}">
        <StackPanel Style="{StaticResource MainStackPanelStyle}">
            <Button Content="Exit" Command="{Binding ExitCommand}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

But `Command` attribute not recognized for i:InvokeCommandAction. Only `CommandName` and `CommandParameter`.

Here is ViewModel code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Sem5_CP.Views;

namespace Sem5_CP.ViewModels
{
    public class AirlineManagerViewModel : ViewModel
    {
        public ICommand OpenFleetManagerCommand { get; private set; }

        private readonly List<Window> childWindows = new List<Window>(); 

        public AirlineManagerViewModel(CloseWindowDelegate close)
            : base(close)
        {
            ExitCommand = new DelegateCommand(Exit);
            OpenFleetManagerCommand = new DelegateCommand(OpenFleetManager);
        }

        private void OpenFleetManager()
        {
            FleetManagerView fleetManager = new FleetManagerView();
            childWindows.Add(fleetManager);
            fleetManager.Show();
        }

        protected override void Exit()
        {
            var result = MessageBox.Show("Exit?", "Exit", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Question);

            if (result == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
            {
                childWindows.ForEach(w => w.Close());
                childWindows.Clear();
                CloseWindow();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have another question then post another question.

Comment: @SirRufo: it is decidedly bad form, and arguably against the community standards, to actually _modify_ the content of someone else's post by removing a question they've asked. It is true that each post should really only have a single question, but it's not your place to remove content from the post, no matter how out of place you think it is. Please limit your edits to improving clarity, formatting, and the like. Do _not_ change the intent of the original post.